# Mapping a real vector to binary vector based on some threshold value

Tags: matlab

Consider a random vector,

Example:

```
 >> testdata = rand(1,10)

testdata =

    0.7314    0.5355    0.3669    0.6349    0.4370    0.1806    0.1148    0.2417    0.7116    0.3056
```

Now lets take a mean over this vector and lets call it our threshold value.

```
>> mean(testdata)

ans =

    0.4260
```

Now anything greater than mean is 1 and anything less than mean is 0.

How can I achieve this more efficiently without using a for loop.

Thanks.

Comment: try `res = testdata>mean(testdata);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testdata>mean(testdata)
```

will return a logical vector with 1 for bigger and 0 else. It will have the size of `testdata` (so this works for matrizes too) and you can use logical operators like:

```
testdata>mean(testdata) & testdata<0.9
```